# How to save the client area of a child Window to a Bitmap file?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, bitmapimage

I have created a windows application using core WIN32 and VC++. In my parent window I have a child window and two buttons "save" and "send".

When user clicks the "save" button I want the `savefileDialog` to be opened and user should be able to save the image as a bitmap file.

The same file should be sent to a remote user using WinSock API.... My problem is, I don't know how to save the screen shot of the window to a bitmap file...

please help me out of this ... I have not used MFC, ATL or WTL....

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
RECT rect     = {0};

GetWindowRect( hwnd, &rect );
ATL::CImage* image_ = new CImage();
image_ -> Create( rect.right - rect.left, rect.bottom - rect.top, 32 );

HDC device_context_handle = image_ -> GetDC();
PrintWindow( hwnd, device_context_handle, PW_CLIENTONLY );
image_ -> Save( filename );
image_ -> ReleaseDC();

delete image_;
```

[`PrintWindow()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd162869%28VS.85%29.aspx) should do the trick.

To save as HBITMAP:

```
HDC hDC       = GetDC( hwnd );
HDC hTargetDC = CreateCompatibleDC( hDC );
RECT rect     = {0};

GetWindowRect( hwnd, &rect );

HBITMAP hBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap( hDC, rect.right - rect.left,
    rect.bottom - rect.top );
SelectObject( hTargetDC, hBitmap );
PrintWindow( hwnd, hTargetDC, PW_CLIENTONLY );
SaveBMPFile( filename, hBitmap, hTargetDC, rect.right - rect.left,
    rect.bottom - rect.top );

DeleteObject( hBitmap );
ReleaseDC( hwnd, hDC );
DeleteDC( hTargetDC );
```

I will leave the implementation of SaveBMPFile up to you ; )

Comment: Is the problem the ATL::CImage ? If so, I can show you how to do it with pure winapi.

Comment: thanks for the kindness, plz brief me the steps i should follow to save the image displayed in a child window to a HBITMAP object......

Comment: You can use CImage in Win32, simply #include <atlstr.h> and 
#include <atlimage.h>. Also #include <atlstr.h>, it wants CString apparently.