# PrintWindow - Capture child window?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, gdi+, gdi

i want to know how to PrintWindow child window ?
Why ? Because on some windows like the folder view, it captures just the frame of the folder but not and the SysListView32 item, so i think i have to capture it separately, or somehow to force it to draw itself, i tried SendMessage with WM_PAINT and WM_SYSCOLORCHANGE but no success.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Here is the same question asked but no answer....
http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=555250

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save the client area of a child Window to a Bitmap file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5950259/how-to-save-the-client-area-of-a-child-window-to-a-bitmap-file)

Comment: No its totally different, i just dont know how to make some child windows to not show black when doing PrintWindow...